# How to add two column names in form validation codeigniter rule

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, bonfire

I am using codeigniter. Below is the form validation set rule

```
unique[bf_product.product_order,bf_product.id]
```

- bf_product = table name
- product_order = column name

  I want to add another column i.e: `product_category` names to `unique` rule in `form validation`.

So that the product can be fetch on the basis of `product_order` and `product_category`, and the user can't input same order no. for a particular category.

**Example:**

1. Product category 1 - product - sort order = 1
2. Product category 1 - product - sort order = 1 `(Not possible,already exist)`
3. Product category 2 - product - sort order = 1 `(Possible)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it can be done by `unique`, As per documentation it checks for a single column only. Would recomment you to go for `callbacks`:

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('ele', 'alias', 'callback_check_product');

function check_product( $ele ){
    #check here with the $ele and return TRUE / FALSE
}
```